# Make Keyboard keys run JavaScript if the mouse isn't in a Textarea/textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like if they press A regardless of the caps for it to pull up Apps, Pressing D pulls up Dashboard. This should only work if their mouse is not in a area where they can type. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code I would follow:

```
onKeyPress {
    if (body.hasFocus && !input.hasFocus ) {
        coolStuff();
    }
}
```

Basically, you have an event listener waiting for your particular key(s) to be pressed. You only execute the coolFunc(), however, if they have focus on your webpage (i.e. not the address bar) and they are not inside a input element.

I would also recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com); it will make your code a lot cleaner and easier to write.

Let me know if you need an actual JS example, not pseudo-code.